# pyserial enumerate ports

Tags: python, pyserial

I need list or enumerate of existing serial ports, 
Till now I was using this method **enumerate_serial_ports()**, but its not working with windows 7. Do you know some alternative how can I find out available serial ports under windows 7?

```
def enumerate_serial_ports():
  """ Uses the Win32 registry to return an 
      iterator of serial (COM) ports 
      existing on this computer.
  """
  path = 'HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM'
  try:
      key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path)
  except WindowsError:
      raise IterationError

  for i in itertools.count():
      try:
          val = winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
          yield str(val[1])
      except EnvironmentError:
          break
```

I get IterationError
[image]

Comment: to Space_C0wb0y: picture was added

Comment: do not raise an nnknown class exception (IterationError), let the traceback help us on what is the real problem ;)

Comment: IterationError is not defined, but it isn't your real problem. First, remove the `try...except` statement and show the error from `key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're raising an `IterationError`, but that exception doesn't actually exist. Maybe you should try raising `EnvironmentError` for that condition as well.

The pySerial docs include some sample code for finding serial ports. Check them out: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#finding-serial-ports

Comment: His problem isn't with the IterationError. Fixing this name won't solve the problem.

Comment: That URL doesn't seem applicable now. Maybe http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#testing-ports instead.

Answer (score 16):

There's now a [list_ports](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports) module built in to pyserial.

```
In [26]: from serial.tools import list_ports
In [27]: list_ports.comports()
Out[27]: 
[('/dev/ttyS3', 'ttyS3', 'n/a'),
 ('/dev/ttyS2', 'ttyS2', 'n/a'),
 ('/dev/ttyS1', 'ttyS1', 'n/a'),
 ('/dev/ttyS0', 'ttyS0', 'n/a'),
 ('/dev/ttyUSB0',
  'Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub ',
  'USB VID:PID=0403:6001 SNR=A1017L9P')]
```

The module can also be executed directly:

```
$ python -m serial.tools.list_ports
/dev/ttyS0          
/dev/ttyS1          
/dev/ttyS2          
/dev/ttyS3          
/dev/ttyUSB0        
5 ports found
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me, Since list_ports.comports() is a generator, I had to do:

from serial.tools import list_ports
for a in list_ports.comports(): print(a)

Comment: @RyanN You can easily turn a generator into a list by wrapping it with list()

Comment: list_ports does not seem to find all the available com ports, because I have a USB serial device that does not show up  using the list_ports generator, yet realterm finds it and puts it in the list of selectable ports without any problem.  It ends up being at COM20, and if I open COM20 with the serial module, it works fine.  But if I want the user to be able to select among the existing ports, I have to make it show up on the list of available ports.

Answer (score 1):

Below you find my helper function to print the names and description of the available com ports, using the `serial` module:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
print(
    "\n".join(
        [
            port.device + ': ' + port.description
            for port in list_ports.comports()
        ]))
```

Example output:

```
python.exe -u listSerialPorts.py
COM4: Sierra Wireless NMEA Port (COM4)
COM12: USB Serial Port (COM12)
COM10: USB Serial Port (COM10)
COM3: Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)
COM5: Sierra Wireless DM Port (COM5)
```